# function returns empty value for std::String

Tags: c++, curl

Using `refresh` to get the output result from as Flask web server, when the function is executed it prints the result needed to the screen but when it is time to print out it does not print the out value and all you get is an empty line

Why is this happening

```
size_t CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* s)
{
    size_t newLength = size * nmemb;
    try
    {
        s->append((char*)contents, newLength);
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& e)
    {
        //handle memory problem
        return 0;
    }
    return newLength;
}

std::string refresh(std::string path) {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    const char* path_ = path.c_str();
    std::string s;
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path_);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "out=");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return s;
}
```

driver code

```
int main() {
    std::string out = refresh(server_path+"/refresh");
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us. What is, for example, `CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString`? What does the function do?

Comment: it is a callback function to get data out of post request

Comment: Good now we can see that crucial piece of code. Now, what efforts of debugging have you made? Have you tried to run in a debugger with breakpoints at e.g. the `CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString` function to see if it gets called (or just print when it gets called, including its arguments)? And if it gets called, what is the contents of the memory pointed to by `contents`? Is the size larger than zero?

Comment: The callback function is called and it has the data i need but when i try to `cout` the variable `out` I don't see it's value

Comment: Is the output in `refresh` working? Does the output of `s` show the correct contents? Is the problem only when printing `out` in the `main` function?

Comment: The ouput in `refresh` is working and I see the data that I need but `out` is empty

Comment: I think you are saying that your `cout << s` prints the expected result, but `return s;` assigning to a new variable `out` leads to `out` having a different value?

Comment: people if I add this line `std::cout << s << std::endl; ` before `return s;` I see the value of `s` which is the value that I need but when `std::cout << out << std::endl;` is executed it does not have a value

Comment: I suspect this question does need a [mre].  It is not normal or expected that a `std::string` would change _because_ it was returned from a function.